# displaying multiple components within a cell of vaadin grid

Tags: grid, vaadin7

Is there any way I can display multiple components(like     CheckBox,     Label etc.) to a single cell of a Vaadin     Grid? The Grid displays data populated dynamically by a    GeneratedPropertyContainer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search the [Vaadin directory](https://vaadin.com/directory#!browse) you will find a few extensions, such as [ComponentRenderer add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/componentrenderer) which allow you to have such features in a somewhat painless way. Below you can see a code sample based on Vaadin v7.7.3 and v1.0.2 of the before-mentioned add-on. Please remember to update and recompile your widgetset.

```java
public class GridWithMultiComponentRenderer extends VerticalLayout {

    private static final String BUTTONS_ID = "buttons";

    public GridWithMultiComponentRenderer() {
        // basic grid setup
        Grid grid = new Grid(new BeanItemContainer<>(Person.class));
        grid.setSizeFull();
        addComponent(grid);

        // add the decorator
        ComponentGridDecorator<Person> gridDecorator = new ComponentGridDecorator<>(grid, Person.class);

        // generate the column which will display the components
        gridDecorator.addComponentColumn(BUTTONS_ID, person -> new HorizontalLayout(
                new Button("Get name", event -> Notification.show(person.getName())),
                new Button("Get surname", event -> Notification.show(person.getSurname())),
                new Button("Get age", event -> Notification.show(String.valueOf(person.getAge())))
        ));

        // set column order
        grid.setColumns("name", "surname", "age", BUTTONS_ID);

        // add some dummy data
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            gridDecorator.add(new Person("Name " + i, "Surname " + i, random.nextInt(99) + 1));
        }
    }

    // POJO for simple binding
    public static class Person {
        private String name;
        private String surname;
        private int age;

        public Person(String name, String surname, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }

        public void setSurname(String surname) {
            this.surname = surname;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: multiple components in grid column]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I could implement my requirement using     ComponentRenderer addon. It works perfectly.

Comment: @Debasish no problem, glad I could help. Usually on StackOverflow, the common way of thanking someone for an answer or comment, is by up-voting it if it was helpful, or select it as the correct answer (click the green `v` symbol in front of the vote number) which will give some reputation points to the person who answered. On the other hand, if the response has no meaningful information regarding the question, you can chose to down-vote it. These actions will help the other users that have a similar question/issue to quickly spot the relevant information (http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Cheers